How to get a user's personal goals?
I can use Performance_Management/Manage_Goals to create and update a user's goals (goals they have created or own), but how do I get a list of them?
E.g.
<soapenv:Body>
     <bsvc:Manage_Goals_Request bsvc:Add_Only="0" bsvc:version="v42.1">
        <bsvc:Manage_Goals_Data>
           <bsvc:Worker_Reference>
              <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">e1541aaaaaaaaaa764515dc7bd0000</bsvc:ID>
           </bsvc:Worker_Reference>
        </bsvc:Manage_Goals_Data>
      </bsvc:Manage_Goals_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>

or Performance_Management/Get_Organization_Goals_Request
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bsvc:Get_Organization_Goals_Request bsvc:version="v42.1">
            <bsvc:Request_Criteria>
                <bsvc:Supervisory_Organization_Reference>
                  <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">e1541aaaaaaaaaa764515dc7bd0000</bsvc:ID>
                </bsvc:Supervisory_Organization_Reference>
            </bsvc:Request_Criteria>        
        </bsvc:Get_Organization_Goals_Request>
    </soapenv:Body>

and the most promising, Integrations/Get_References but how do I filter the list?
     <bsvc:Get_References_Request bsvc:version="v42.1">
         <bsvc:Request_Criteria>
            <bsvc:Reference_ID_Type>Goal_Reference_ID</bsvc:Reference_ID_Type>
         </bsvc:Request_Criteria>
      </bsvc:Get_References_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>

other things I've considered are getting all the goals in the org and filtering out for a user's goals ... getting a user's profile and hoping goals would be attached ...

In the Get_Workers request, there is a parameter for "Include_Goals" that will return back the data in "Worker_Goal_Data"

Human_Resources/Get_Workers/Include_Goals [0..1] GENIUS!

This only gets superficial data though, like the reference, name and completion status. I still have to look up things like progress and milestones :(
